# Module is not callable

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm getting module not callable error in U-Net

```
def unet():
inputs = Input((1,512, 512))
conv1 = Conv2D(width, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(inputs)

conv1 = BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(conv1)
conv1 = Conv2D(width, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

conv2 = Conv2D(width*2, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool1)
conv2 = BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(conv2)
conv2 = Conv2D(width*2, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

conv3 = Conv2D(width*4, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool2)
conv3 = BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(conv3)
conv3 = Conv2D(width*4, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

conv4 = Conv2D(width*8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool3)
conv4 = BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(conv4)
conv4 = Conv2D(width*8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv4)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

conv5 = Conv2D(width*16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool4)
conv5 = BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(conv5)
conv5 = Conv2D(width*16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv5)

up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
conv6 = SpatialDropout2D(0.35)(up6)
conv6 = Conv2D(width*8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv6)
conv6 = Conv2D(width*8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv6)

up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
conv7 = SpatialDropout2D(0.35)(up7)
conv7 = Conv2D(width*4, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv7)
conv7 = Conv2D(width*4, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv7)

up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
conv8 = SpatialDropout2D(0.35)(up8)
conv8 = Conv2D(width*2, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv8)
conv8 = Conv2D(width*2, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv8)

up9 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
conv9 = SpatialDropout2D(0.35)(up9)
conv9 = Conv2D(width, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv9)
conv9 = Conv2D(width, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv9)
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
return model
```

Please look into the code and reply me with solution

Below is the error

```
<ipython-input-12-dd57276e32d9> in unet()
     38     conv5 = Conv2D(width*16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv5)
     39 
---> 40     up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
     41     conv6 = SpatialDropout2D(0.35)(up6)
     42     conv6 = Conv2D(width*8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv6)

TypeError: 'module' object is not
```

Comment: Sounds like `merge` is a module, as in `import merge`. You're probably meant to use a function within.

Comment: I have used that import merge in my code, but still getting an error

Comment: No I'm saying `import merge` indicates that `merge` is a module, which can't be called like a function. You probably want `merge.something(...)`.

Comment: Try to format your code better, i.e. with a good indentation and the adapted imports. This way people will help you faster and better. Don't forget to post the whole traceback as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [merge](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) layers in Keras have been refactored some time ago, so you have to use the `concatenate` function for your use case, like this:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate

up6 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], axis=1)
```

Its the same for your other merge calls.